# Saxon.Api.DynamicError, "Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {exslt.org/common}node-set()"

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, saxon

Hi Experts/Michael Kay

I got "Saxon.Api.DynamicError - Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {exslt.org/common}node-set(). There is no Saxon extension function with the local name node-set" by using saxon9he - v9.4.0.2. My XSLT file is calling "EXSLT". please help me to resolve the issue.

```
public static StringWriter XSLT2(string sourceFile, string XSLT)
{
    Processor processor = new Processor();

    var setting = new XmlReaderSettings { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse };
    XmlReader reader2 = XmlReader.Create(sourceFile, setting);
    XdmNode input = processor.NewDocumentBuilder().Build(reader2);
    //XPathCompiler compiler = processor.NewXPathCompiler();
    //compiler.DeclareNamespace("exsl", "http://exslt.org/common");

    // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
    //Stream XsltTransformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(XSLT).Load();
    XsltTransformer transformer = processor.NewXsltCompiler().Compile(new Uri(XSLT + @"\mekontopic.xsl")).Load();
    transformer.InputXmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();

    // Set the root node of the source document to be the initial context node
    transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

    // Create a serializer
    StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
    Serializer serializer = new Serializer();//serializer.SetOutputWriter(Console.Out);
    serializer.SetOutputWriter(s);

    // Transform the source XML to System.out.
    transformer.Run(serializer);
    return s;
}
```

Thanks in advance

SARAN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, Saxon-HE does not provide any extension functions; you have to upgrade to Saxon-PE.

However, the exslt:node-set() extension is so widely used in XSLT 1.0 code that we relented on this one, it's available in Saxon-HE 9.6 and (I think, need to check) also in 9.5.

There's another workaround if you need it: implement it yourself. Just add a customization module to your stylesheet (a main module that imports what was previously the main module) which contains the code

```
<xsl:function name="exslt:node-set" as="node()">
  <xsl:param name="n" as="node()"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="$n"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: I have tried 9.5 also same issue found, i like to use as per advice will implement the XSLT myself. Thanks a lot for great help.

Comment: Michael Kay: I just tried with 9.6 HE, and it appears that 

  function-available('exslt:node-set')

still returns false. Maybe the function is there, but function-available() isn't aware of it?

Comment: Yes, thanks, we've noted the function-available() problem as a bug here: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/2212

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.saxonica.com/feature-matrix.html, EXSLT functions are not supported by the HE version. You need to either upgrade to a higher edition, or (preferably) rewrite your stylesheet to take advantage of XSLT 2.0, which does not require the EXSLT extension functions.

Or perhaps you can downgrade to a XSLT 1.0 processor such as Saxon 6.5 or Xalan.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you very much for quick reply. I'm using 3rd party XSLT so that i cannot change my XSLT, where/how can get/buy Saxson-EE.dll?

Comment: @saravanans, the commercial editions of Saxon can be downloaded from http://www.saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml#current but you need to buy a license in their online shop to be able to run them. However if all you want to do is use `exsl:node-set` then I would first consider to rewrite the stylesheet to remove any calls to that function as it is not necessary in XSLT 2.0 and is basically doing nothing in Saxon PE/EE other than returning its argument.