# Reflexive calls to Java methods are not available under Saxon-HE

Tags: java, spring-boot, xslt, saxon

I am new to xslt and springboot. I have developed microservice using spring boot. I have xslt file as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java">
    <xsl:template match="//ProcessInput">
        <xsl:variable name="dateTimeFmt" select="java:format(java:java.text.SimpleDateFormat.new ('yyyy-MM-ddHH:mm:ss'), java:java.util.Date.new())"/>
        <xsl:variable name="date" select="concat(substring($dateTimeFmt,1,10),'T',substring($dateTimeFmt,11))"/>
        <RMessage>
            <header>
                <RMessageId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="IMD/@id"/>
                </RMessageId>
                <RMessageSchemaVersion/>
                <RSource>ABC</RSource>
                <RDestination>XYZ</RDestination>
                <RDateTimeSent>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
                </RDateTimeSent>
            </header>
            <body>
                <xsl:copy-of select="IMD/node()"/>
            </body>
        </RMessage>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting Below error :

```
Error at char 98 in xsl:variable/@select on line 4 column 145 
  XTDE1425: Cannot find a 2-argument function named
  Q{http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java}format(). Reflexive calls to Java methods are not
  available under Saxon-HE
  in built-in template rule for /ProcessInput in the unnamed mode
```

And I have used below dependencies in my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
    <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
    <version>9.9.0-2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Guess you'll need to buy Saxon-PE or -EE if you want to keep using Saxon

Comment: So what is the aim of the use of your Java code? It looks like you can do it in pure XSLT 2/3 with `<RDateTimeSent><xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/></RDateTimeSent>`, if needed with the help of the XPath `format-dateTime` function. Additionally, if you really need to call into Java from XSLT with Saxon 9 HE, then you can make use of the mechanism of integrated extension functions http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/integratedfunctions/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saxon.Api.DynamicError, "Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {exslt.org/common}node-set()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622567/saxon-api-dynamicerror-cannot-find-a-matching-1-argument-function-named-exslt)

Comment: @Martin-Honnem &Erwin thanks I think it would be better to upgrade to XSLT2 and use java built in XML Transform rather than buying saxon paid version

Comment: Saxon-HE 9.9 supports XSLT 2/3 where you can use `<xsl:value-of select="current-dateTime()"/>` as shown and it is open-source software, you don't have to buy a license. Not sure what you refer to with "java built in XML Transform" but the version Xalan that Sun/Oracle provides in the JRE only supports XSLT 1.

Comment: @Martin, Thanks I tried with XSLT 2 and Saxon-HE 9.9 its working.

Answer (score 6):

Well, the message means what it says. You are trying to use a feature called "reflexive extension functions". This feature tries to match an XPath function call with the Java classes and methods available on the classpath (in this case `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`). This feature is not available in the Saxon-HE product. You can solve the problem in a number of ways:

- Upgrade to Saxon-PE (which costs a small amount of money)
- Replace your use of this Java method with the standard XPath `format-date()` function
- Use the mechanism for calling out to Java which IS available in Saxon-HE, namely "integrated extension functions" (see under "Extensibility" in the Saxon documentation).